# App Engine 1.7.3: Need more info about Django 1.4 support

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel, django-1.4, djangoappengine

App Engine 1.7.3 was just announced, claiming "Django 1.4 is now fully supported for Python 2.7". Please provide more information. Is this referring to the django-nonrel source code on Github for 1.4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not django-nonrel. This announcement means that you can now use Django 1.4 as part of your libraries directives in app.yaml as documented here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Comment: Thanks. I understand now from the link you included that it's basically Django minus model interface. We need django-nonrel for the model interface and other minor details.